# MYSQL: ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION [db].LEN does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, function, mariadb

I've successfully created a function but I'm unable to run it.

Here is my InitCap(InputString) function, which was successfully created and added to my database:

```
DELIMITER //

drop function InitCap;

CREATE FUNCTION InitCap(InputString varchar(4000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(4000) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

    DECLARE  OutputString          VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE  Index1                INT;
    DECLARE  Char1, PrevChar1      CHAR(1);

    SET OutputString = LOWER(InputString), Index1 = 1;

    WHILE Index1 <= LEN(InputString) DO

        SET Char1     = SUBSTRING(InputString, Index1, 1),
            PrevChar1 = CASE WHEN Index1 = 1 THEN ' '
                                 ELSE SUBSTRING(InputString, Index1 - 1, 1) end;

        IF PrevChar1 IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(') THEN

            BEGIN
                IF PrevChar1 != '''' OR UPPER(Char1) != 'S' THEN
                    SET OutputString = STUFF(OutputString, Index1, 1, UPPER(Char1));
                END IF;
            END
            ;

        END IF;

    SET Index1 = Index1 + 1;

    END WHILE;

    RETURN OutputString;

END  //

DELIMITER ;
```

I've tried to run the following:

> select InitCap(string_variable) from table;

but keep getting

> ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION [db].LEN does not exist

Comment: Try `length()`.  For `initcap()`, I think you are out-of-luck.  Perhaps you want to switch to using Oracle?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length

Comment: @GordonLinoff isn't `initcap()` OP's custom function?

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, it wanted LENGTH() instead of LEN().  What's strange is that it didn't throw an error when creating the function in the first place, if it didn't like the syntax...

Comment: @EricCallahan . . . This is a delayed evaluation thing.  It allows for the definition of the function to change *after* this function is created.